# Kibana: how can I sort by the relative frequency of one of possible values in char?

Tags: bar-chart, kibana, kibana-4

I'm working on following visualization: frequency of specific job build status result per job. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Statuses are fetched from Jenkins, but it it irrelevant here]

The question is - how can I sort by one of the specific values, say, by "success"?
I've taken tens of attempts to attack the issue, re-read docs but I'm still failing. Let's say that the field name is `buildStatus`.

Comment: Can you use custom matrics for sorting by total number of success

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to order your elasticsearch output as described [in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting_by_a_metric.html)?

You should also have a look at this [Kibana blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-aggregation-execution-order-and-you?q=order%20kiban), maybe it will help you.